# SIngleton object initialization and dependency injection

Tags: java, singleton

I usually create singleton classes using singleton holder pattern like this:

```
public class Foo {

    private static final class SingletonHolder {
        private static final Foo INSTANCE = new Foo();
    }  

    private Foo(){}

    public static final Foo getInstance(){
        return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

}
```

Everything ok. But, what about if I need inject one dependency to initialize the singleton object?

In that case, I add one method `initialize` that receives the dependency and must be called just one time:

```
public class Foo {

    private static final class SingletonHolder {
        private static final Foo INSTANCE = new Foo();
    }  

    private Foo(){}

    public static final void initialize(Dependency d) {
        SingletonHolder.INSTANCE.setDependency(d);
    }

    public static final Foo getInstance(){
        return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

}
```

Am I in the right way? Is there another solution? I know that it depends on the program, my logic and so on... but how generally should be solved this problem?

Comment: Instead of using a singleton, why not create a single instance and pass it around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating it. In a few places I worked (including my current one) we don't try to enforce singletons. All the wiring for the actual application is done in one place, so if you searched for usages of constructor you should find one in `src` and probably multiple in `test`. See the code below.

A few disadvantages of your approach:

- you lose immutability, `Foo`'s dependency can change
- both `setDependency` and `initialize` methods are test code in production
- your constructor doesn't create a valid object, a second half of constructor is in `initialize` method which you have to remember to call after calling constructor
- `SingletonHolder` is a boiler plate code, I am not sure why don't you just declare `public static final Foo instance` field instead?
- it is still possible to create multiple instances of `Foo` using reflection API and object serialisation mechanisms

```
public class Foo {

    private final Dependency dependency;

    public Foo(Dependency dependency) {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }

    // ...
}

public class Dependency {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this approach is that the `initialize` method can be invoked more than once, and there is no indication in your code that setting the dependency is being handled with thread safety.

If you're fine with that, then your lazy initialization idiom is fine.

Otherwise, you could throw an `IllegalStateException` or otherwise silently do nothing when the dependency is being set more than once within your singleton instance.

**Edit**

As [Andy Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/202009/andy-thomas) says, you also aren't checking whether the dependency is set before `getInstance` is invoked, or at least your code doesn't display it.

Comment: In addition, the `initialize()` method might not have been invoked at all before the first call to `Foo.getInstance()`.